# Cannot use GSAP in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, gsap

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

I get the above error text.
The settings in tsconfig.json are

```
 "target": "ES5", 
 "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
"module": "ES2015", 
"moduleResolution": "node10"
```

I don't see any compile errors, so I guess GSAP is not loading?
Do you know what the reason is?

```
import { gsap, Bounce } from 'gsap';

const MAX = 50;

const rects = [];
for (let i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
  const rect = document.createElement("div");
  rect.className = "rect";
  rect.style.width = `calc(100vw * ${1 / MAX})`;
  rect.style.height = `calc(100vw * ${1 / MAX})`;
  rect.style.left = `calc(100vw * ${i / MAX})`;
  rect.style.top = `-100px`;
  document.body.appendChild(rect);
  rects.push(rect);
}


const tl = gsap.timeline({ repeat: -1, repeatDelay: 1 });
rects.forEach((rect, index) => {

  tl.add(
    gsap.to(rect, {
      duration: 3,
      y: (window.innerHeight * 3) / 4,
      ease: Bounce.easeOut,
      delay: Math.random(),
    }),
    0
  );
});
```

I would like to move the above index.ts file.